# Swift .SQLCLIENT how can I void completion?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, xcode, sqlclient

Hello i have a problem. Im using SQLClient library and connect to my Database and run my query successful.Now my problem is  I get the result too late for tableview because of the the completion handler . I run this code on ViewDidLoad.I want to get data earlier for my tableviews. How can I avoid completion handler ?

```
    self.client.connect( ip, username: "sa", password: "freebsd", database: database) { success in
        self.client.execute("SELECT Distinct " + colum + " FROM ambEssenTrinken" + wherebed , completion:  { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
          for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
              for row in table {
                  for (columnName, value) in row {

                     print(value)
                      query.append(value as! String)

                  }
              }
          }
            self.client.disconnect()
      })
      }

    return query
```

Comment: instead of calling it in `viewDidLoad` call your function is `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Ünal you could simply reload your table from inside the completion block. Do use DispatchQueue.main.async.

Comment: I have tried with reload but i have not only one  tableview i does not work...can you makean example with DisparchQueue.async on my code please ?